# Pushing a file to a desktop app using aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

I need to push file to a C# desktop app that I'm creating. I'm planning to use Amazon web services (aws) and specifically SQS and S3. My idea is to long poll the SQS queue continuously in a separate thread. If there is a message it will contain a link to download it from S3.

Is this a good method of pushing files to a desktop app using aws or are there better methods?

I also looked at Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS), but it seems to be more suited to mobile devices?

Thanks

Comment: can you share your code. remove secret key etc. am writing similar app and need help. amrik.net at g mail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its should work fine; just keep in mind that messages in an SQS Queue will expire after 14 days, but as long as your desktop runs more frequently than that, it should work OK.